# DNS serving up different IP addresses dependent on www or non-www?

Tags: dns, ip

I am in the process of moving the website traffic for `adadarters.com` from old host to new host. We are keeping old host for various reasons, including mail and ASP files that we don’t want to move, so I simply modified the A record to point to the IP for new host. After 10 hours it has still not *really* propagated, even though it appears that it has. I have been doing `ipconfig` /`flushdns` all day.

What’s happening is that `adadarters.com` serves up the new IP (`74.220.215.66`) and `www.adadarters.com` serves up the old IP (`65.254.231.127`). If you try and type in the URL without `www`, it appears to redirect to `www` and sends you to old host.

The way I figured out was `nslookup adadarters.com 205.171.3.66` (my ISPs IP address) vs `nslookup www.adadarters.com 205.171.3.66`.

Also, a traceroute to `adadarters.com` vs `www.adadarters` traces the route to new and old IP addresses.

New host says DNS looks fine to them. Old host says settings look fine to them too, and that I just need to wait longer for it to propagate. But why would `www` propagate differently than non-www? I think they are just putting me off because they don't know (one reason they are the old host).

Any ideas about what might be happening?If by some chance this has resolved by the time you look, the old host files have the logo on right, new has logo on left and is a WordPress site.

Comment: You say that you 'have been doing ipconfig /flushdns all day' but this only affects your own computer, not any upstream DNS servers that are performing the query for you. It is worth using an independent DNS lookup service at times like this, like mxtoolbox or dnsstuff.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don’t assume “sabotage” from an ISP in a case like this.

> New host says DNS looks fine to them. Old host says settings look fine
>   to them too, and that I just need to wait longer for it to propagate.
>   But why would www propagate differently than non-www? I think they are
>   just putting me off because they don't know (one reason they are the
>   old host).

First off, I’ve dealt with tons of ISPs over the years and I don’t think they would blow you off in this way. Maybe they won’t make as strong an effort as you think they should, but I doubt they would sabotage a DNS switch like this.

#### DNS propagation seems fine now.

That said, DNS propagation seems fine now. Check the results for [`www.adadarters.com` here](https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.adadarters.com) and [`adadarters.com` here](https://dnschecker.org/#A/adadarters.com). Both clearly show `74.220.215.66`.

But then looking at the DNS TTL (time to live) records via [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) it seems that the TTL for both `www.adadarters.com` and `adadarters.com` was/is set to 3600 seconds (aka: 60 minutes). Here are the results for `adadarters.com`:

```
dig +nocmd adadarters.com +noall +answer
adadarters.com.     3600    IN  A   74.220.215.66
```

And then a similar command for `www.adadarters.com`:

```
dig +nocmd www.adadarters.com +noall +answer
www.adadarters.com. 3600    IN  A   74.220.215.66
```

3600 seconds (aka: 60 minutes) is not exactly what you want the TTL to be when doing a DNS IP address switch. Read on.

#### DNS propagation, TTL and the waiting game.

You say that:

> After 10 hours it has still not *really* propagated, even though it
>   appears that it has.

Well seeing the TTL was 3600 it should have propagated after at least 1-2 hours. But in my experience, the way a DNS IP address switch should happen is at least 2 hours before the switch—maybe even a day before the switch—the TTL should be set to 300 (aka: 5 minutes).

Then when you do the switch, within 5 minutes or so DNS servers across the world know to check for new data. And even when I have done that it has sometimes taken 24-48 hours for some straggler DNS servers to catch up to the change. Which is all to say DNS IP address changes like this is not an exact science and you should plan accordingly.

Which means you need to make sure a DNS IP address change like this happens during some slow period for your website. Like at the end of the day or even on the weekend. And then you just have to sit and wait.

Typically any errors caused by you screwing up a DNS entry will be apparent within the first hour or so. But past that, it’s really just a waiting game see how the DNS changes propagate. 95% of the DNS servers in the world should be fine within an hour or so; and the rest will just trickle changes over the next day or so. After 48 or so, DNS changes should be propagated and accepted globally.

The whole reason for that is some DNS server admins respect the TTLs of DNS entries. But others have their DNS servers set to basically ignore TTL values no matter what. Why? Debatable, but it happens.

Comment: This DID eventually propagate. I am not sure whether OldHost fixed something to make it happen or whether this one just took longer than I am used to. Thanks to all.